# Error: %1 is not a valid Win32 application

Tags: npm, gulp, laravel-5.1, laravel-spark

I have just installed a new laravel spark in a new laravel application and am having this error when i run gulp.

```
C:\App>gulp
[12:22:52] Using gulpfile ~\App\gulpfile.js
[12:22:52] Starting 'default'...
[12:22:52] Starting 'sass'...
[12:22:52] 'sass' errored after 64 ms
[12:22:52] Error: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
C:\App\node_modules\laravel-elixir\node_modules\gulp-sass\node_modules\node-sass\vendor\win32-x64-46\binding.node
at Error (native)
at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
at require (module.js:384:17)
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\App\node_modules\laravel-elixir\node_modules\gulp-sass\node_modules\node-sass\lib\index.js:16:15)
at Module._compile (module.js:434:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:452:10)
at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
[12:22:52] Error in plugin 'run-sequence'
Message:
An error occured in task 'sass'.
[12:22:52] Finished 'default' after 74 ms

C:\App>
```

I have followed the procedure as instructed 
[here](https://github.com/laravel/spark)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed the problem by installing python version 3.0 and above will do